# Redis Cache Issue When Imported as DLL in ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis

I'm encountering a peculiar issue with my Redis cache when trying to use it in an ASP.NET Core API project. Here are the details:
I originally implemented Redis caching in a class library project, and it worked perfectly when reference to class library directly. However, when I converted the class library to a DLL and imported it into an ASP.NET Core API project, the Redis cache no longer functions as expected

**Error message:**

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Boolean StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase.StringSet(StackExchange.Redis.RedisKey, StackExchange.Redis.RedisValue, System.Nullable`1<System.TimeSpan>, Boolean, StackExchange.Redis.When, StackExchange.Redis.CommandFlags)'.'

```
using Blog.Auth.Data;
using Blog.Auth.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using RedisHelepr;

namespace Blog.Auth.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly AuthDbContext _dbContext;
        public TestController(AuthDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }


        [HttpGet("products")]
        public IEnumerable<Product> Get()
        {
            RedisHelepr.CacheService _cacheService = new RedisHelepr.CacheService("127.0.0.1:6379"); 
            var cacheData = _cacheService.GetData<IEnumerable<Product>>("product");
            if (cacheData != null)
            {
                return cacheData;
            }
            var expirationTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(5.0);
            cacheData = _dbContext.Products.ToList();
            _cacheService.SetData<IEnumerable<Product>>("product", cacheData, expirationTime);
            return cacheData;
        }
    }
}
```

Shows error on this line:

```
 _cacheService.SetData<IEnumerable<Product>>("product", cacheData, expirationTime);
```

Comment: I changed the project type to Class Library (.NET Standard 2.0) and set the 'Copy Local' property to 'true.' Now it works! I'm not sure if this is the correct way. Can I be sure of it?